# Font issue in setting in UILabel iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts, uistoryboard

I am using custom fonts in my iOS App. Two of the fonts named `quicksand_bold.ttf` and `quicksand_book.ttf` are causing issue. All of the other fonts are working perfectly fine but this QuickSand font is not appearing as the two different types in the fonts,

[image]

neither is is showing different styles

[image]

both the files have been imported properly and the target is also set for them. Also the names of the fonts are added in the info.plist. Can anyone point out something I am missing or something I should do to get them both work. All the other fonts are working perfectly fine as they should.

**UPDATE**

Here are the screenshots of the info.plist and the font names from the projects
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you add `Fonts provided by application` in your Info.plist ?

Comment: Yes i added these fonts in Fonts provided by application in the info.plist. Other fonts that are added are working but these two. @tnylee

Comment: Did you recheck if you added correctly the font names in info.plist ?

Comment: In Xcode 7 in order to use in Xib or Storyboard, adding to project is enough. (Be sure is the same name). To use in code, check this to find your problem: http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/

Comment: @tnylee i have updated the question with the screenshots of my info.plist and project.

Comment: @OnikIV I followed the same tutorial to use custom fonts. And as i said about, all the other fonts are working fine just these two are causing troubles. :(
I am using xcode 6.4 though

Comment: @AhsanEbrahim can you double click on the font's and check if the name are different for both the fonts in the Font Book on mac. As i guess both the fonts can have same name thats why they are not displayed as two different fonts.

Comment: You are right @sneha but the styles are being shown different. One is showing Bold and one is showing Book, then why is this not happening in xcode :(

Comment: Are you able to use both the font programatically ?

Comment: I wanted to use them programmetically but I couldnt. I then checked it by going in storyboard but they were not even available there. I figured out a way to use these two. Just posting it as the answer. @Sneha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By getting a hint from @sneha's comment, I checked the names of these two fonts, both were the same. I installed the fonts in my MacBook rather then importing them to my project, restarted my xcode then i found these two in the storyboard with the same name and two different styles (Book and Bold).
For using these fonts programmatically i used NSLog to figure out the names of the font and the names are `QuicksandBook-Regular` and `QuicksandBold-Regular`.
So you can programmatically set these as

`myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"QuicksandBook-Regular" size:12.0];`

and

`myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"QuicksandBold-Regular" size:12.0];`